# WidlFly creates service on each call

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, wildfly, wildfly-8

On each call I see this message in log:

```
INFO  [org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean] Creating Service {https://.../Service/}Service from WSDL: vfs:/C:/wildfly/bin/content/my.ear/lib/service-1.1.jar/META-INF/wsdl/Service.wsdl
```

org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy used to make call always same, from pool.
And there no problems with other service. How to fix that?